# Awk with subshell initialized variables

Tags: bash, awk

Why do all these not work?

```
$ echo "1" | awk '{ d=$(echo hi); print d }'

$ echo "1" | awk '{ print $(echo hi) }'

$ echo "1" | awk '{ d=$(date); print d }'
```

All print "1" instead of "hi" / current date.

What is wrong?

If I do it outside awk it works alright:

```
$ d=$(echo hi); echo $d; -> prints "hi"
```

My end goal is to be able to do something like this:

```
$ cat dates | awk ' { d=$(date --date=$1 +"%s"); print d } '
```

I want to go over a list of dates:

```
2021-12-26T22:24:08+00:00
2021-12-26T22:24:18+00:00
2021-12-26T22:26:12+00:00
2021-12-26T22:28:07+00:00
```

And display the unix timestamp of each datetime.

Comment: Because you guess syntax instead of reading about it.

Comment: `d=$(echo hi); print d` wouldn't work in a C or Fortran program either because neither of them are shell and neither is awk. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn the awk language.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks mate

Comment: @konsolebox I didn't want anyone to know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using GNU `date`, you can read the file with  dates directly with `-f`:

```bsh
$ cat file
2021-12-26T22:24:08+00:00
2021-12-26T22:24:18+00:00
2021-12-26T22:26:12+00:00
2021-12-26T22:28:07+00:00
```

```bsh
$ date -f file +%s
1640557448
1640557458
1640557572
1640557687
```

```bsh
$ date -f file +%s%t%c
1640557448      Sun Dec 26 23:24:08 2021
1640557458      Sun Dec 26 23:24:18 2021
1640557572      Sun Dec 26 23:26:12 2021
1640557687      Sun Dec 26 23:28:07 2021
```

---

Awk is its own programming language, and you can't use shell expansions in `awk` programs.  The `$(...)` construct in `awk` does something very different from what it does in the shell (it accesses the field whose number is the result of the expression in the parenthesis, as in `$(1+2)`, which is the same as `$3`, which is the value of the 3rd field in the current record).

If you had *really* wanted to use `awk` for this, you would have wanted to use `substr()` to pick out the various part of each date on each line in the input file, and then `mktime()` with those strings to create a Unix timestamp.  The `mktime()` function is non-standard but supported by common `awk` implementations (see your `awk` manual).

The following interprets the timestamps read from the input as in the UTC time zone.

```c
BEGIN { FS = "[-T+:]" }

{
        ts = mktime(sprintf("%.4d %.2d %.2d %.2d %.2d %.2d",
                $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6))

        off = -60*(60*$7 + $8)
}

/-..:..$/ { off = -off }

{ print ts + off }
```

I don't need to use `substr()` here as I'm splitting the time on characters in the set `-T+:` and therefore can access the different parts of the timestamps directly as fields.

```bsh
$ TZ=UTC awk -f script file
1640553848
1640553858
1640553972
1640554087
```

Answer (score 0):

[@they's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684045/273579) provides you the solution for you specific need, so you should use his solution. But just in case you wonder how to run a command inside `awk` and store it in a variable, you can do that using the `getline` function. From the man pages of `awk(1)`:

```
command | getline [var]
                      Run command piping the output either into $0 or var,
                      as above.
```

So here are few example for your first attempts:

```
$ echo "1" | awk '{ "echo hi" |getline d; print d }'
hi

$ echo "1" | awk '{ "date" | getline d; print d }'
Mon Dec 27 02:47:29 PST 2021
```

And here's how could have get your expected functionality by running `date` inside `awk` (Again, don't actually use this command, use [@they's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684045/273579), this is just for the sake of explanation):

```
$ cat dates | awk ' { "date --date="$1" +%s" |getline d; print d } '
1640557448
1640557458
1640557572
1640557687
```

Comment: I wouldn't call getline like that - use something like `d=( ("date" | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" ) ; print d` instead. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. This approach is very innefficient as it spawns a subshell every time you call `date` though - if you need to call Unix date for every input line there's no efficient way to do it but it's a bit better done in a loop before calling awk rather than inside awk.

Comment: Also, `"date --date="$1" +%s"` is passing the value of `$1` to the shell unquoted, you should use `"date --date=\047"$1"\047 +%s"` instead so that the input data being passed to the shell is within single quotes.